# How can i navigate table id one screen to another screen and how to get id to second screen using React-Navigation-V5 and PHP MySql?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-navigation-v5

As you can see I am trying to navigate one screen with table id to another screen and also trying to get id to second screen with the help of the react-navigation-v5.

n App.js file I am using stack navigation to navigate screens and In MainActivity is used to show only the Name of students.When pressing on name of the student it navigate with student id to SecondActivity screen.In SecondActivity screen it show the details of the student.Like Id, name etc with the help of the id.To get Id in SecondActivity screen using 'this.props.navigation.state.params.FlateListIdHolder' to fetch id.

When I am pressing on student list name its showing the error below.

**Console.error:The action "NAVIGATE" with payload {"name":"SecondActivity","params":{"FlateListClickItemHolder":"pankaj"}} was not handaled by any navigator.**

**Do you have a screen named 'SecondActivity'?**

#### **App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import MainActivity from './pages/MainActivity';
import SecondActivity from './pages/SecondActivity';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="MainActivity " component={MainActivity} />
              <Stack.Screen name="SecondActivity" component={SecondActivity} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

#### **MainActivity**

```
export default class MainActivity extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isLoding : true
        }
        this.arrayholder = [];
    }
    OpenSecondActivity(id){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondActivity', {FlateListIdHolder: id });
    }
   componentDidMount() {
        return fetch('http://192.168.43.89:8080/FilterJsonListView/CollegeStudentsList.php')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson
                }, function () {
                    this.arrayholder = responseJson;
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            })
    }
    FlateListItemSeparator = () => {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    height: 1,
                    width: "100%",
                    backgroundColor: "#000"
                }}
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoding) {
            <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
                <ActivityIndicator /
                >
            </View>
        }
        return (
            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.dataSource}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlateListItemSeparator}
                    renderItem={({ item }) =>
                        <Text
                            key={item.id}
                            style={styles.FlatListItemStyle}
                            onPress={this.OpenSecondActivity.bind(this, item.name)}
                        >
                            {item.name}
                        </Text>
                    }
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />   
            </View>
            );
    }
}
```

#### **SecondActivity**

```
export default class SecondActivity extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            IdHolder: '',
            NameHolder: '',
            SemesterHolder: '',
            DepartmentHolder: '',
            PhoneNumberHolder:''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://192.168.43.89:8080/FilterJsonListView/Filter.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({

                id: this.props.navigation.state.params.FlateListIdHolder

            })

        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    IdHolder: responseJson[0].id,
                    NameHolder: responseJson[0].name,
                    SemesterHolder: responseJson[0].semester,
                    DepartmentHolder: responseJson[0].department,
                    PhoneNumberHolder: responseJson[0].phone_number

                })

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
    render() {
        console.log(id);
        return (
            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }} >
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >
                        {'id=' + this.state.IdHolder}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >
                        {'name=' + this.state.NameHolder}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >
                        {'Semester=' + this.state.SemesterHolder}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >
                        {'Department=' + this.state.DepartmentHolder}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >
                        {'Phone Number=' + this.state.PhoneNumberHolder}
                    </Text>

                </View>

            </View>
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have try your code, and it work fine :) My suggestion is maybe you should rebuild your application.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion i will try.. :-)